# Angular uses wrong router-outlet

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing

I have a problem with Angular routing. I have main app routing module and sub module with its own routing module and router-outlet but routes defined in this submodule are shown using root router outlet and not the child one.

My folder structure:

[image]
My code listings

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**app.component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**home-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LandingPageComponent},
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class HomeRoutingModule { }
```

**home.component.html**

```
...
<div class="inner cover">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
...
```

That's what I get when I use empty path - it opens home component properly.

[image]

But when i enter /register i get plain html from login.component.html without template in home.component.html file

[image]

**EDIT**

I added name to child outlet

```
<router-outlet name="home"></router-outlet>
```

Changed route names to:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LandingPageComponent, outlet: 'home'},
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent, outlet: 'home' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, outlet: 'home' }
];
```

Now I got that error:

[image]

**EDIT 2**

I try to access those routes in 2 ways:
A link(which may be incorrect):

```
<a routerLink="/login">Log In</a></li>
```

Or typing manually:

```
localhost:4200/login
```

Comment: In home-routing  add  children: [ { ...} ] inside the routes where you define the routes child

Answer (score 1):

In Angular 2, router outlets can be named:

```
<router-outlet>
    <router-outlet name="children"></router-outlet>
</router-outlet>
```

App:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

Home:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LandingPageComponent, outlet: 'children'},
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent, outlet: 'children' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, outlet: 'children' }
];
```

You can even define child routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', 
    component: HomeComponent, 
    pathMatch: 'full', children: [
      { path: '', component: LandingPageComponent, outlet: 'children'},
      { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent, outlet: 'children' },
      { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, outlet: 'children' }
    ] 
   }
];
```

http://onehungrymind.com/named-router-outlets-in-angular-2/

Comment: Try only giving a name to the child outlet.

Comment: Still same problem :/

Comment: Done! I hope it can be fixed easily :)

Comment: Needless to use `name="children"`, works for me only with the tag

Answer (score 0):

If you want those 3 components to be rendered **inside of the HomeComponent** in a named outlet, then you need to define the following routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', 
    component: HomeComponent, 
    pathMatch: 'full'
   },
   { path: 'landing', component: LandingPageComponent, outlet: 'children'},
      { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent, outlet: 'children' },
      { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, outlet: 'children' }
];
```

And inside of app.component.html add the named router outlet

```
....//html template 
<router-outlet name="children"></router-outlet>
....//html template
```

**EDIT 1:**

To navigate to the named outlets you need to use the following routed links:

```
//inside of home.component.html
 <a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { children: ['login'] } }]">Take me to login!</a>
```

The generated link will look like:

```
root/(children:login)
```

More info in the following [link to the docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#displaying-multiple-routes-in-named-outlets)

**EDIT 2:**

I changed the original **routes** and the **component template** where the named outlet is added. Why?

it is not possible, as far as I know, to have a named outlet with an empty path (''). The empty path tells angular that the named outlet is empty (no component is currently rendered in it).

Comment: can you please add in the question how are you trying to access the routes? :)

Comment: Got it for you :)

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: Edited answer, named outlets are kind of tricky indeed, I struggled today a little to configure a named outlet in one of my projects

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem has to do with declarations. I can not know for certain since you didn't show the code in your **app.module.ts** and **home.module.ts** file and have not tested this fully myself.

A component needs to be declared inside the module connected to the template with the desired routing outlet. In your case the login component would need to be added to "declarations" in your home.module.ts file and removed from "declarations" in the app.module.ts file.

Angular does not seem allow you to reuse the same component in multiple routing-outlets unless they are in the same template, since it would cause an error stating "x component declared in multiple modules".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This doesn't qualify to be a answer or offer any solution to the existing problem. This should be placed as a comment. If you cannot comment then you shouldn't misuse the answers/solutions sections as it only results in down votes which means reduced reputation making it harder to earn the sufficient reputation to post comments. I would recommend you delete this post.

Comment: I hope my editing is good enough to make this qualify as an answer :)